# Using "Spatial" extension to read excel is giving error with versions of Duck DB 0.9.0 and above versions

Tags: python, duckdb

DuckDB throws `"NotImplementedException: Not implemented Error: GDAL Error (6): Adding too many columns to too many existing features"`.
The same code worked well with DuckDB version 0.8.1. Below is the code which throws the error. I am using python 3.10. Is this an error related to spatial? Have even tried by re-installing DuckDB. The issue still persists.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE 'DummyTable' AS
    SELECT * FROM ST_Read(
        'file_name', layer='Sheet1', open_options=['HEADER=FORCE']
    );
```

Comment: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb_spatial/issues/230